# how to route one table to another table within same page in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I think it easy but it seems hard to me please help.
What I need to do, is to route from one table to another table within the same page.

what I have done so far:

```
<table class="table  bg-gray-400 mt-3">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>A</th>
              <th>B</th>
              <th>C</th>
              <th>D</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let import of imports; let i=index">
          <td>{{import.id}}</td>
          <td>{{import.a}}</td>
          <td>{{import.b}}</td>
          <td>{{import.c}}</td>
          <td>{{import.d}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

When user click on id it will route to different table with different data and within same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do it by simply adding a link or a click listener to your `<td>`, like following:

**your.component.html:**

*Option 1:*

```
...
<td><a (click)="navigateToOtherTable(import.id)">{{import.id}}</a></td>
...
```

*Option 2:*

```
...
<td (click)="navigateToOtherTable(import.id)">{{import.id}}</td>
...
```

And in your component you would need to add the function:

**your.component.ts**

```
navigateToOtherTable(id: string) {
    // TODO navigate to your table with the id
}
```